# OTA QC ALM :ActiveX component can't create object:Set Scheduler = theTestSet.StartExecution("")

Tags: vb.net, hp-quality-center

I am trying to execute below OTA code from VBS file to have each test in the test set executed

but I am getting an error ActiveX component can't create object at the step

Set Scheduler = theTestSet.StartExecution("")

My System details:

OS: Windows 7 Professional
System Type: 64-bit Operating System
ALM Version: 12.0

Code:

Set ALMConnection = CreateObject("TDAPIOLE80.TDConnection")

'Connect to server
ALMConnection.InitConnectionEx "http://alm.zebra.com/qcbin"

'Authenticate user
ALMConnection.Login "uk1346", "aJanuary$2018"

' Connect to project
ALMConnection.Connect "ZEBRA_PROJECTS", "Zebra_Global_Projects"

Set TSetFact = ALMConnection.TestSetFactory

Set tsTreeMgr = ALMConnection.TestSetTreeManager

nPath = "Root\" & Trim("Automation\Automation Dry Run")

Set tsFolder = tsTreeMgr.NodeByPath(nPath)

If (tsFolder Is Nothing) Then

MSGBOX "Folder is not found"

Else

MSGBOX "Folder is found"

End If

Set tsList = tsFolder.FindTestSets("Dry Run")

If tsList.Count > 0 Then

MSGBOX "FindTestSets found more than one test set"

ElseIf tsList.Count < 1 Then

MSGBOX "FindTestSets: test set not found"

End If

Set theTestSet = tsList.Item(1)

MSGBOX theTestSet.ID
'
Set Scheduler = theTestSet.StartExecution("")

Scheduler.RunAllLocally = True

Scheduler.Run

Set execStatus = Scheduler.ExecutionStatus

MSGBOX execStatus

Set ALMConnection = Nothing

Answer (score 0):

Running the “ALM Client Registration” solved my problem: http://XXXX/qcbin/start_a.jsp?common=true